# MATLAB: Color of sphere distorts color scheme values

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following MWE, showing a surf-plot and a sphere,

```
figure(1)
[xx yy] = meshgrid(0:0.1:pi, 0:0.1:pi);
surf(xx, yy, zeros(size(xx)), 0.001*sin(xx), 'EdgeColor', 'none')

hold on
[xS,yS,zS] = sphere(50);
surf(xS+1, yS+1, zS+1,'FaceColor', 'k', 'edgecolor','none')
hold off
colorbar
```

The amplitude of the surf-plot is so small that one cannot see what value it has wrt. the colorbar. This is due to the sphere, which has a large amplitude and "distorts" everything.

Is there a way to somehow force the figure to not take into account the color of the sphere? Or maybe change its "amplitude"? I tried changing `caxis`, but it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up manually the limits of your colorbar with `caxis`

your colors are `C=0.001*sin(xx)`

then, after the plotting, add `caxis([min(C(:)) max(C(:))])` and you will have the limits are you wish

[image]